# The method was called on null happend Incidental

Tags: flutter, dart

Show the codes below:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "list_page": (context) => PoiList(),
        "distance_page": (context) => Distance()
      },
      home: HomePage()
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  AMapController _aMapController;

  BuildContext _buildContext;

  double _clickedLat;
  double _clickedLng;


  void onAMapCreated(AMapController controller) {
    _aMapController = controller;
  }

  void onPoiNaviButtonClicked(double lat, double lng) async{
    print(lat);
    print(lng);

    _clickedLat = lat;
    _clickedLng = lng;

    caculate(lat, lng);
  }

  void caculate(double lat, double lng) async{
    if (_aMapController == null){
      print("_aMapController == null");
    }
    _aMapController.caculteDistanceBetweenTwoPois({"lat":lat, "lng":lng}); //This is the error codes.
  }


  void onDidCaculateDistance(int distance){
    Navigator.of(_buildContext).pushNamed("distance_page", arguments: {"distance":distance, "poi":{"lat": _clickedLat,"lng":_clickedLng}});
  }


  List<Map<String, double>> pois = [
    {'lng': 119.932382, 'lat': 31.615883},
    {'lng': 119.934098, 'lat': 31.619684},
    {'lng': 119.946801, 'lat': 31.608574},
    {'lng': 119.957788, 'lat': 31.589859},
    {'lng': 119.949548, 'lat': 31.628162}
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Widget build");
    _buildContext = context;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand, //未定位的widget占满stack
          children: <Widget>[
            AMap(onAMapCreated: onAMapCreated, onPoiNaviButtonClicked: onPoiNaviButtonClicked, onDidCaculateDistance:onDidCaculateDistance),
            Positioned(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("定位");
                  },
                  child: Text("定位"),
                ),
                right: 20,
                bottom: 60),
            Positioned(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("缩小");
                      _aMapController == null
                          ? null
                          : _aMapController.setZoomLevel(6);
                    },
                    child: Text("缩小")),
                right: 20,
                bottom: 120),
            Positioned(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("放大");
                      _aMapController == null
                          ? null
                          : _aMapController.setZoomLevel(10);
                    },
                    child: Text("放大")),
                right: 20,
                bottom: 180),
            Positioned(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("搜索");
                      //Flutter中准备poi点经纬度坐标数组,在原生地图上显示

                      _aMapController == null ? null : _aMapController.showNearByChargingStation(pois);
                    },
                    child: Text("搜索")),
                right: 20,
                bottom: 240),
            Positioned(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
//                      jump(pois, distance)
                      print("跳转");
//                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("list_page", arguments: {'pois': pois, 'mapController':_aMapController});
                    },
                    child: Text("跳转")),
                right: 20,
                bottom: 300),
          ],
        ));
  }

}
```

In HomePage(StatelessWidget), I define a variable: AMapController _aMapController;
In the build function, I created a AMap widget(This is iOS native mapView). When the AMap created. The callback below will be called, and the _aMapController variable will be initialized.

```
  void onAMapCreated(AMapController controller) {
    _aMapController = controller;
  }
```

onPoiNaviButtonClicked() function is another callback triggered by ios native code.
in the onPoiNaviButtonClicked() function, I call caculate() function. 
in the caculate() function. The _aMapController sometimes will be null！
It is very strange. It is not happend everytime! It is just happend sometimes?
Why!

And it seems jump to secondpage(Distance()), then return to homepage, it will happend sometimes!

Comment: which is the method which was called on null? post the stackTrace, if you call xMethod() of a object like object.xMethod() while the object is being null the above error is thrown

Comment: @iamyadunandan _aMapController.caculteDistanceBetweenTwoPois({"lat":lat, "lng":lng});  this is error codes

Comment: Do a try catch and print the stack